# Cannot add CSS attributes to <span>

Tags: css, html

In a CSS file I have the following rules:

```
div.breadcrumbs span {
    position: relative;
    left: -120px;
    height: 16px;
    line-height: 16px;
    margin: 0 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

div.breadcrumbs img {
    margin: 0 -20px;
    padding: 5px 5px 0px 5px;
}

div.breadcrumbs a {
    color: #88263F;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

The rules for `img` and `a` work, but not for `span`.

Also something does not work like

```
span {
    display: none;
}
```

At the moment I have no clue how to debug this.

Comment: span display:none working perfectly nice.. without having look at your html codes we couldnot help you out.. see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mYCjx/

Answer (score 4):

In principal, your posted CSS works.

If your HTML looks like this...

```
<div class="breadcrumbs">
    These are <span>breadcrumbs</span> in a line...
</div>
```

and this is your CSS:

```css
div.breadcrumbs span {
    position: relative;
    left: -120px;
    height: 16px;
    line-height: 16px;
    margin: 0 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
span {
    display: none;
}
```

then the `span` element is not shown as you intended.

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/qyu5A/

You may have other problems such as other CSS rules that are conflicting and preventing the `display: none` property from working correctly.

There is nothing wrong with the positioning of an inline element, but you may not get exactly what you expect depending on the line height and surrounding content.

You may want to learn more about how the CSS cascade and specificity work.

Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascade

**Note:** The `height` property is ignored for inline elements.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for your hints, especially the fiddle!

Playing around with it I found the following code snippet also in the CSS file:

```
body.home div.breadcrumbs span { position:relative; left:0; }
```

Placing "div.breadcrumbs span" after this and deleting "position: relative;" it works as exspected.